# Load a txt file -> open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory). I'm pretty sure the problem is not the path, but i can't find the mistake

Tags: java, android, file, path, enoent

I'm trying to load a file and save what's wrote in it but I always get "open failed: ENOENT". The file is in the same folder of java files. Rest of code works nice, and if I run separately also the method read().

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView list;
    Intent intent;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        intent = new Intent(this, Second_activity.class);

        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

        System.out.println(read());

        String [] dati = {};

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, dati);

        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        list.setOnItemClickListener(listener);
    }

    private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener listener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String itemValue = (String) list.getItemAtPosition(position);
            intent.putExtra("listValue", itemValue);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    };

    public String read(){
        String data = null;
        try {
            File myObj = new File("com/example/myapplication2/calendario.txt");
            Scanner myReader = new Scanner(myObj);
            while (myReader.hasNextLine()) {
                data = myReader.nextLine();
            }
            myReader.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("An error occurred.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return data;
    }
}
```

Comment: "The file is in the same folder of java files." -- then it is not on the device. Package your content as an asset (`src/main/assets/`) and use `AssetManager` and its `open()` method to get an `InputStream` on its contents.

Comment: `I'm pretty sure the problem is not the path` I am pretty sure you are wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Your file is on your android studio project path, and then you need put it in the right place **raw folder**, second get it the right way. File("....") is for file in **device path**.

**Get Started.**

You need move your file to resource/raw folder, for create this folder just right click on res folder, select New> Directory, then studio will open a dialog box and it will ask you to enter the name.

[image]

and write “raw” and click OK. Open res folder and you will find your raw folder under it.

[image]

Then you can put your files like .txt, .mp3 in this folder, and to get one you can use this code or similar.

```
InputStreamReader inputStream = new InputStreamReader(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.calendario))
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader();
String line = reader.readLine();
while (line != null) { ... }
```